# Нужна помощь в расположении изображения

Tags: android, imageview

Scroll Activity.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.nexxie.diplom2.Eur_S10_ALL_E_001"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_eur__s10__all__e_001">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:id="@+id/eur__e__s10__all_001"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/s10100BA270"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/s10100BA260"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eur__e__s10__all_001"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

для увеличения текста я использовал PhotoView. Хотелось бы поднять изображение наверх и вместе с  ним и TextView подтянуть к ImageView
[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Попробуйте заменить RelativeLayout на LinearLayout с вертикальной ориентацией

Comment: У imageView попробуйте атрибут добавить android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Cпасибо! Ваш ответ помог мне!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб С вашим вариантом я пробовал, не помогло.

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, вы б в ответ это написали)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сейчас оформлю)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы скорректировать границы `imageView` без потери его `drawable`   помогает атрибут `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`.